# Mapping unique id of two data frame in python

Tags: python

I have two data frame, Df1 and Df2.

```
Df1

ID      Name
A132    AB Investment fund
A430    Micheal Business Unit
A203    Baja Finance
A101    Motocorp solution pvt ltd
A037    Dojas Corp 


Df2

ID      Name
A037    Dojas Corp ltd
A530    Jack Finance Company
A101    Motocorp pvt ltd
A132    AB Investment fund comp
A812    J K Solutions
```

I want to Map Df1['ID'] with Df2['ID'], which ever ID's are common in both the data frame for those records create another data frame Df3 as below:

```
Df3

ID     Df1['Name']                 Df2['Name']

A132   AB Investment fund          AB Investment fund comp
A101   Motocorp solution pvt ltd   Motocorp pvt ltd
A037   Dojas Corp                  Dojas Corp ltd
```

Comment: Are these pandas dataframes?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed); consider adding tags more relevant to your question (`pandas` maybe?).

Comment: This is a relational equal join on the ID column. In pandas, this is done with the `merge` method.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101